# How to define a datatemplate for Tooltip in silverlight?

Tags: c#, silverlight-4.0

How to define a datatemplate for Tooltip in silverlight?

I was able to find samples on creating a control template and assigning it to the tooltip template property , but how can i create a tooltip data template and assign it?

Comment: what exactly do you need to do? show different tooltips depending some data or something like that?

Comment: I think you need a DataTemplateSelector, but I'm in a hurry, so I prefer writing a good comment than a bad answer : http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wpf-tutorial-how-to-use-a-datatemplateselector

Comment: It aint that complicated. How do i assign a datatemplate to Tooltip ? Currently i m adding the content below the tooltipservice.tooltip  . Like this

Comment: <TextBlock Text="{Binding Nucleus_id}">
                                                <ToolTipService.ToolTip>   
                                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                                                        <Border CornerRadius="2" BorderBrush="LightGray" BorderThickness="1" Padding="3">
                                                           <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">